how to unlock ubuntu 24.04 from anydesk remotely
After restarting the server from anydesk and entering the password this screen remains black and I can't do anything anymore. I have to go to where the server is to unlock it


Ensure a monitor is connected to the remote device. By connecting one, the computer will detect that a display is connected and will keep the display drivers on. If there is one connected, make sure that it is on and awake. If you do not wish to connect a monitor.
if this is done:
Currently AnyDesk might need an active display signal to function properly. As a workaround you can use a headless adapter, to emulate a visual signal.
https://www.reddit.com/r/AnyDesk/comments/esd3m1/anydesk_in_linux_gives_black_screen/
